# Can the "combine" function be used to only pass only one agent at a time?

Tags: anylogic

I am new to AnyLogic and I apologize in advance if this is a too easy problem to solve, however, here it is:

I am looking to send one agent from two differnet delays into the next delay function.
For now, the combine block will only allow to move on, if two agents arrived from the previous two delay functions. I used the combine function as the delay function will only allow one incoming connection at a time.
How can I manipulate the "combine function" to not wait for the second agent to arrive?

Is it even the right function?

Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2mk3.png)

I have tried to look up an example in the tutorial book, but wasn't successful.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by function you mean block... A block and a function are not the same thing

You can connect any number of blocks to a delay, so the combine block is not needed in your case, since you don't really want to combine anything.

Also, you can't control the combine to not combine

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot. Indeed works w/o the combine block.